# With maven how to bundle all dependencies AND my Java project filesin the output jar when using `maven-assembly-plugin`?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using `maven-assembly-plugin` to create a output jar from my maven project. The relevant protions of my `pom.xml` look like this:

```
.
.
.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      .
      .
      .
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        .
        .
        .
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>my.package.TheApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        .
        .
        .
    </plugins>
</build>
.
.
.
```

When I run `mvn clean install assembly:single`` the resulting jar file does  contain the dependencies, but it does *not* contain my project files. Running the jar with

```
java -jar TheApp-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get the message `Error: Could not find or load main class my.package.TheApp`. **So how can I include my project files?** (I thought of setting `useProjectArtifact`, but [according to the maven-assembly-plugin doco](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) this property is by default `true`.)

Comment: Remove the configuration `<sourceDirectory>..</sourceDirectory>` and keep convention over configuration. furthermore bind the plugin to the package phase as documented here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html#Execution:_Building_an_Assembly and in the end you can use `mvn clean package` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By poking around on Stack Overflow I [found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/65889):

Run `mvn clean compile assembly:single` instead of `mvn clean install assembly:single`. :-)

Or even better bind in the `pom.xml` the assembly to the package phase (thanks @ khmarbaise!):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  .
  .
  .
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and then run `mvn clean package` (or `mvn clean install` if you want to).

Comment: Bind the plugin to the lifecycle so you can use `mvn clean package` instead add supplemental goal...and `install` is not necessary...